# My app disappeared from "tablet" google play but still available for phone

Tags: android, google-play

I have my app published for couple of months on Google play. People with phones and tablets are able to download it. Surprisingly, sometimes in the last 2 weeks, something with google play changes and my app is only available for phone (I can't find it when I search using a tablet).

Any idea if there is something changed or I need to implement? I don't specify any device screen size in my manifist file so it should be fine ,right?

Thanks a lot

EDIT. Below is the manifest file. The thing that this application was supporting tablet but all of the sudden it stopped

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myApp"
    android:versionCode="5"
    android:versionName="3.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    ........
   ////Activities are here
..

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you post your manifest file?

Comment: When you lookup your app in play.google.com in a browser, does it say something about compatibility for your devices?

Comment: I added the manifest of the app (removed the app name though)

Comment: @ott-- how do you find compatibility? I found it in google play through my browser but nothing about compatibility

Comment: See e.g. http://imageshack.us/a/img842/622/compat1.png - it's just beyond the install button. What's the name of your app, so I can echeck it for my devices.

Comment: It is Rental Property Manager.. Please check it as I couldn't find it

Comment: what is your package name!! I will also have a look

Comment: com.propertymanagerlite

Comment: I tried to add the support screens option for all the screens. So I will have to wait for 4 hours before the whole thing appears on google. I dont know if that will work

Comment: As an update the supportscreen option worked but the probelm it is forcing to set the minsdk to 9 because xlarge s not supported in sdk 8.there gotta be a way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution 
I used the support screen tag and I explicitly set the xlarge screen to true. 
I contacted Google and they said it is a issue they are investigating.

Comment: This just happened to my app, crap!

Comment: @Snake You wrote: "I used the support screen tag", does it mean it was wrong to use it and you had to remove it after Google told you to, or you had to use it, in order for the app to be available for tables? Didn't get clear from your comment. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yea i removed the support tag from my manifest as Google fixed the issue. Now the app appears on all devices as intended. I used it initially as a work around for the bug that Google play had

Answer (score 4):

Try adding this to your Manifest

```
<compatible-screens >
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Good Luck!

```
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="480" />
   <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
   <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" />
   <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="480" />
```

Edit: for xxhdpi you must use "480"

Comment: That's absolutely not recommended.  This will block new phones configuration like xxhdpi from installing your app.

See (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html, caution section)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

To:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony.SEND_SMS" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.vibrate" android:required="false"/>
```