# App works fine on tablet, but not found on google play

Tags: android, titanium, google-play, appcelerator

I have an app that I am now on version 1.4 of it. I test on an android `tablet` as well as an android `phone`.

In this most recent update, the app shows up on my `phone` when I search for "vforum"

When I do the same thing on my `tablet`, it doesn't show up. I was curious as to why it wasn't showing up so I got a direct link to the app page and opened that in google play. I can see the app is there, however, there is an alert that says "Your device isn't compatible with this version." The `tablet` is even listed under the "approved devices" in the googe play dashboard.

I find that odd because I used the `tablet` to test the app on.

So I am using

- Ti SDK 3.1.0
- Android 4.0.3 w/ google apis sdk
- The `phone` (which works from google play) is running android 4.1.2
- The `tablet` (which doesn't show up in google play) is running android 4.0.3

Can anyone shed some light on this as to why I can't see my app on my `tablet` from google play? After this release of my app, I am unable to see it on the `tablet`. My previous versions have worked fine.

**EDIT**

results of `aapt dump badging appname.apk`

```
package: name='com.dop.vforummobile' versionCode='6' versionName='1.4.0'
sdkVersion:'8'
application-label:'Vforum Mobile'
application-icon-120:'res/drawable/appicon.png'
application-icon-160:'res/drawable/appicon.png'
application-icon-240:'res/drawable/appicon.png'
application: label='Vforum Mobile' icon='res/drawable/appicon.png'
launchable-activity: name='com.dop.vforummobile.VforumMobileActivity'  label='Vforum Mobile' icon=''
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-implied-permission:'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE','requested WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.wifi'
uses-implied-feature:'android.hardware.wifi','requested android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE, or android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE permission'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen'
uses-implied-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen','assumed you require a touch screen unless explicitly made optional'
main
other-activities
other-services
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales: '--_--'
densities: '120' '160' '240'
native-code: 'armeabi' 'armeabi-v7a'
ronnimac:platform-tools ronnie$
```

**SOLUTION (Using Titanium mobile, tiapp.xml)**

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <tool-api-level>9</tool-api-level> //-- Added this line because xlarge wasn't supported until android sdk version 9+
    <manifest android:versionCode="7" android:versionName="1.4.1">
        <supports-screens 
            android:smallScreens="true"
            android:normalScreens="true"
            android:largeScreens="true"
            android:xlargeScreens="true" //-- Added xlargeScreen
            android:anyDensity="true"
        />
    </manifest>
</android>
```

Comment: This is a link to the app if anyone is wondering https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dop.vforummobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the badging, I see three problems.  Your supports-screens does not include xlarge and your densities list doesn't include 320.   Finally, it doesn't show a targetSdkVersion.  I think you should edit your manifest to fix these and then rebuild.

I'm basing the list above off comparisons to my own application's badging.  I've personally seen a missing targetSdkVersion cause Google Play to get confused.

Comment: Not sure where to run this command. I built the app using Titanium mobile. I tried running aapt in terminal, but I don't think that is the right spot. I am currently googling where to run it

Comment: The only thing I could guess from that is the tablet is a density other than what is listed under the `densities` output..although `support-any-density` is set to true..hmmm

Comment: Interesting, I don't have explicit settings for the densities and screen sizes.  What version of the SDK are you using to actually build?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tips. I unfortunately don't have an `AndroidManifest.xml` file. I am using Titanium mobile to build this app and the manifest file is built automatically. I can edit some of the android settings through the Titanium project file, tiapp.xml. Looks like this is a titanium issue possibly. Then again I just found this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821518/my-app-disappeared-from-tablet-google-play-but-still-available-for-phone?rq=1

Comment: That other link is definitely suspicious.  Good luck.

Comment: looks like maybe I need to do this: http://developer.appcelerator.com/doc/mobile/android-custom-androidmanifest although not sure why its worked before without it

Comment: Fixed it! The problem ended up being that I did not have xlarge specified as you stated. It is just weird to me that all my other versions have shown on google play before this last update.